# Can't create table (errno: 150) with added KEY

Tags: mysql, create-table, errno

I have a problem with adding part of db to ready db.
It looks like:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `kreker92_diplom`.`diplom_sites_users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kreker92_diplom`.`diplom_sites_users` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idusers` INT NOT NULL,
  `idsite` INT NOT NULL,
  `datecreate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `dateedit` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `idsite`, `idusers`),
  INDEX `fk_diplom_sites_users_diplom_users1_idx` (`idusers` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_diplom_sites_users_diplom_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idusers`)
    REFERENCES `kreker92_diplom`.`diplom_users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `kreker92_diplom`.`diplom_sites_data`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kreker92_diplom`.`diplom_sites_data` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idsite` INT NOT NULL,
  `siteurl` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `mobsiteurl` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `uridir` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `sitetype` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `panelstyle` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `publish` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `multilang` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `callbtn` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `sinchronization` TIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `idsite`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `kreker92_diplom`.`diplom_sites`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kreker92_diplom`.`diplom_sites` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idsite` INT NOT NULL,
  `datecreate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `dateedit` DATETIME NULL,
  `sites_data_idsite` INT NOT NULL,
  KEY ix_diplom_sites_idsite (idsite),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `idsite`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sites_users`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idsite`)
    REFERENCES `kreker92_diplom`.`diplom_sites_users` (`idsite`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sites_sites_data1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idsite`)
    REFERENCES `kreker92_diplom`.`diplom_sites_data` (`idsite`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

But phpMyAdmin sad that:

## 1005 - Can't create table 'kreker92_diplom.diplom_sites' (errno: 150)

abd it starts from:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `kreker92_diplom`.`diplom_sites`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
```

But i've made a KEY:

> KEY ix_diplom_sites_idsite (idsite),

So what is wrong I make?

Answer (score 0):

For a field to be a `foreign key` its parent field must have an `'INDEX'` defined on it.
As per documentation on `foreign key` constraints:

> REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)

In `'diplom_sites'` table,

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_sites_users`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idsite`)
    REFERENCES `kreker92_diplom`.`diplom_sites_users` (`idsite`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
```

the referred parent field `'diplom_sites_users( idsite )'` has not `'key'` defined on it was only part of a composite key. Define a separate key on it.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kreker92_diplom`.`diplom_sites_users` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idusers` INT NOT NULL,
  `idsite` INT NOT NULL,
  `datecreate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `dateedit` DATETIME NULL,

  INDEX `ix_users_idsite`( `idsite` ), -- <------ this was missing

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `idsite`, `idusers`),
  INDEX `fk_diplom_sites_users_diplom_users1_idx` (`idusers` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_diplom_sites_users_diplom_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idusers`)
    REFERENCES `kreker92_diplom`.`diplom_users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Refer to**:

- [**MySQL Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
>       [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
>       REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
>       [ON DELETE reference_option]
>       [ON UPDATE reference_option]
>
> reference_option:
>       RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION

Comment: Thanks for ur helping! I've added INDEX `ix_diplom_sites_users_idsite`( `idsite` ),
where u say but I still have the same error

Comment: Add similar indexes for other referred columns too. For example, `diplom_sites_data.idsite` too needs an index defined. You have to define indexes for all such referred fields.

Comment: I've found misstake. I needed to delete ENGINE = InnoDB.